# Renaming files with sed, escaping issues

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, awk

I'm trying to write a bash script to remove spaces, underscores and dots and replace them with dashes.  I also set to lowercase and remove brackets. That's the (long) second sed command, which seems to work.

The first sed call escapes the original names with spaces with '\ ' like when I tab complete, and this is the issue I think.

If I replace 'mv -i' with 'echo' I get what I think I want: the original filename escaped with backslashes and then the new name.  If I paste this into the terminal it works, but with mv in the script the spaces cause problems.  The escaping doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in "$@"; do
    mv -i $(echo "$a" | sed -e 's/ /\\\ /g') $(echo "$a" | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' -e 's/_/-/g' -e 's/ /-/g' -e 's/---/--/g' -e 's/(//g' -e 's/)//g' -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]//g' -e 's/\./-/g' -e 's/-\([^-]*\)$/\.\1/')
done
```

The other solution is to put quotes around the names, but I can't work out how I would do this.  I feel like I've got close, but I'm stumped.

I've also considered the 'rename' command, but you cannot do multiple operations like you can with sed.

Please point out any other issues, this is one of my first scripts.  I'm not sure I got the "$@" or "$a" bits completely correct.

Cheers.

edit:

sample input filename

```
I am a Badly [named] (file) - PLEASE.rename_me.JPG
```

should become

```
i-am-a-badly-named-file--please-rename-me.jpg
```

**edit2: my solution, tweaked from gniourf_gniourf's really helpful pure bash answer:**

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in "$@"; do
    b=${a,,}                       #lowercase
    b=${b//[_[:space:]\.]/-}       #subst dot,space,underscore with dash
    b=${b//---/--}                 #remove triple dash
    b=${b//[()\[\]]/}              #remove brackets
    if [ "${b%-*}" != "$b" ]; then #if there is a dash (prevents filename.filename)
        b=${b%-*}.${b##*-}         #replace final dash with a dot for extension
    fi                           
    if [ "$a" != "$b" ]; then      #if there has been a change
        echo '--->' "$b"           #
        #mv -i -- "$a" "$b"        #rename
    fi
done
```

This only fails if the file had spaces etc and no extension (e.g `this BAD_filename` becomes `this-bad.filename`. But these are media files and should have an extension, so I would have to sort them anyway.

Again, corrections and improvements welcome. I'm new at this stuff

Comment: And now you have two problems.

Comment: I do, care to elaborate?

Comment: no. look at my answer, you'll see how to achieve your algorithm in a good and sane way.

Comment: Thank you! (Your answer wasn't there when I replied).  I'm still not sure why I have two problems though.

Comment: `mv -i -- "$a" $(echo "$a" |  sed ....` seems to work without escaping, perhaps I read so much about covering this that I didn't try the obvious.

Comment: Of course it works... that's actually what I used in my solution `:)`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the records, look:

```
$ a='I am a Badly [named] (file) - PLEASE.rename_me.JPG'
$ # lowercase that
$ echo "${a,,}"
i am a badly [named] (file) - please.rename_me.jpg
$ # Cool! let's save that somewhere
$ b=${a,,}
$ # substitution 's/[_ ]/-/g:
$ echo "${b//[_ ]/-}"
i-am-a-badly-[named]-(file)---please.rename-me.jpg
$ # or better, yet:
$ echo "${b//[_[:space:]]/-}"
i-am-a-badly-[named]-(file)---please.rename-me.jpg
$ # Cool! let's save that somewhere
$ c=${b//[_[:space:]]/-}
$ # substitution 's/---/--/g' (??)
$ echo "${c//---/--}"
i-am-a-badly-[named]-(file)--please.rename-me.jpg
$ d=${c//---/--}
$ # substitution 's/()[]//g':
$ echo "${d//[()\[\]]/}"
i-am-a-badly-named-file--please.rename-me.jpg
$ e="${d//[()\[\]]/}"
$ # substitution 's/\./-/g':
$ echo "${e//\./-}"
i-am-a-badly-named-file--please-rename-me-jpg
$ f=${e//\./-}
$ # substitution 's/-\([^-]*\)$/\.\1/':
$ echo "${f%-*}.${f##*-}"
i-am-a-badly-named-file--please-rename-me.jpg
$ # Done!
```

Now, here's a 100% bash implementation of what you're trying to achieve:

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in "$@"; do
    b=${a,,}
    b=${b//[_[:space:]]/-}
    b=${b//---/--}
    b=${b//[()\[\]]/}
    b=${b//\./-}
    b=${b%-*}.${b##*-}
    mv -i -- "$a" "$b"
done
```

yeah, done!

All this standard and known as [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

**Remark.** For a more robust script, you could check whether a has an extension (read: a period in its name), otherwise the last substitution of the algorithm fails a little bit. For this, put the following line just below the `for` statement:

```
[[ a != *.* ]] && { echo "Oh no, file \`$a' has no extension..."; continue; }
```

(and isn't the `*.*` part of this line so cute?)

Comment: Brilliant.  You've given me a whole new (better) approach.  What's the '--' for in the move command.  It's not in the man file.

Comment: The `--` means end of options. It's just in case a file starts with a hyphen, it would confuse `mv` trying to interpret it as an option. Use it if your version of `mv` supports it! it will make your script much more robust.

Comment: It also appears to put the extension on the beginning of the filename so the two bits need swapping.

Comment: @lipidicman Oh, I had mistyped the last substitution statement... it's fixed now, sorry about this.

Comment: Don't be sorry, the solution is just what I needed.  Now I'm still a little confused, if I put echo in front of the mv command I see that the filenames aren't escaped.  Are the "" enough when using mv (not echo mv), and why did my original stab fail in this respect?

Comment: The double quotes are your life savers! Instead of putting `echo` in front, put this: `printf -- '---> %s\n'` and you will see on each line starting with `--->` each argument separately. It's a wonderful way to understand a lot! You can even play with arguments (read filenames) that contain newlines, e.g., `touch $'a\nfilename\nwith\nnewlines\nlol.jpg'`. Enjoy `:)`

Comment: the for statement doesn't work (true for files with extensions), and shouldn't it be placed before the last manipulation?

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this with [`rename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/rename) :

```
rename 's/[_\s\.]/-/g' *files
```

from the `shell` prompt. It's very useful, you can put some [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) code inside if needed.

You can remove the `-n` (dry-run mode switch) when your tests become valids.

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: Thank you.  As I say my problem with rename (and I have the Perl version) is that I couldn't do the multiple substitutions like I could with sed.  Your first example gets a few things done, but I'll need to put the final '-' back as a dot for the file extension and do the lowercase operation, the parenthesis and brackets and remove the '---' which has arisen from ' - '

Comment: Done, sorry for the omission.  The sed expressions show that, but I shouldn't have expected anyone to decode them.

Comment: I need to save that stop sign.